# How to find the Union of two contours in OpenCV python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, geometry, polygon

I am trying to find the union of two contours using OpenCV in Python. The catch here is that I only want to use the contour points to perform the specific operation without drawing the contours as described in the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170224/how-to-join-union-contours-in-opencv). I have tried the solution given in the answer and was hoping to find some solution which does not involve drawing the contours first and then again using the findContours function to find the merged contour.

Comment: show us the contours. as a picture and as data.

Comment: you can use a library like `shapely` [link](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union)

Comment: I don't know of any built-in method in OpenCV, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19475433/1377097) should help if you want to make your own.